# How to display GIF in pyqt5 application - python

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

Im looking for a way which I could play animated GIF in my pyqt5 python application... It should be displayed for the time when somthing specific happening until it ends.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a QMovie object as follows:

```
self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, gifWidth, gifHeight))
self.gif = QtWidgets.QMovie('yourGifLocation.gif')
self.label.setMovie(self.gif)
self.gif.start()
```

source: https://developpaper.com/how-to-display-gif-picture-in-pyqt5/